# Status bar color changed after Xcode 13 update

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, colors, status

Before updating to xcode 13, the status bar's background color matched the color of the navigation bar. When I updated to xcode 13, the status bar is behaving strangely. It is showing different background colors in different view controllers. Some are black, some are gray, and some are transparent. I tried overriding the status bar style but it didn't work. There has been no change in the code whatsoever since the update. I want the status bar's background color to match that of the navigation bar.

[image: Status bar comparison before and after xcode 13]

Answer (score 1):

You did not give code example how you are setting status bar - are you using `statusBarManager`? Maybe you are using some code that became deprecated?

You can try set it with extension with `statusBarManager` in `viewDidAppear`:

```
extension UINavigationController {

    func setStatusBar(backgroundColor: UIColor) {
        let statusBarFrame: CGRect
        if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
            statusBarFrame = view.window?.windowScene?.statusBarManager?.statusBarFrame ?? CGRect.zero
        } else {
            statusBarFrame = UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame
        }
        let statusBarView = UIView(frame: statusBarFrame)
        statusBarView.backgroundColor = backgroundColor
        view.addSubview(statusBarView)
    }
}
```

And then in your view call it like:

```
self.navigationController?.setStatusBar(backgroundColor: #COLOR) 
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setNeedsLayout()
```

Answer (score 0):

**SwiftUI answer**:

Try adding `.ignoresSafeArea()` to whatever parent of your child views is. I encountered a similar issue back in the day and solved it by something like this:

```swift
struct HomeView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            <code>
            
            Spacer()
        }.ignoresSafeArea()
    }
}
```